# prevent postback using jquery,javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Here is my HTML code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input id="q" required />
    <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

I'm trying the HTML 5 `required` feature in asp.net. The above code works. But a post back also occurs. Is there a way to prevent the post back using JavaScript, jQuery or any other method? I tried to prevent the post back using jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn').click(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

But this makes the `required` validation not to fire.

***Note: There are more than one button in the form.***

Comment: Please don't use "leetspeak". There is no character limit for questions. It's "are" not "r".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change "click" event to "submit", and bind it not to btn but to form

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form1').on("submit", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: but what if i have more than one button on the form

Comment: why do you care? I thought we are talking about submitting the form. You can have 5 submit buttons within the form - no one would work as the "submit" event triggers the post back

Comment: we r talking about preventing the post back with the required html5 feature intact.This won't work in case i have more tha n 1 button on the form

Comment: @iBlue" Why? Have you tried it at all? Please elaborate. It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8uk3b/1/.

Comment: @FelixKling check this http://jsfiddle.net/8uk3b/2/ scenario.I fill in first text and click search but it shows validation for second text box.In dat case solution won't work.

Comment: yeah in your fiddle you are using it not correctly. If you want two seperate field, with two seperate buttons, you of course should use two seperate forms :)

Comment: ok, if you put into your form an "asp net input button" or how its called, you have the ability to set the "enabled" or "disabled" property. Do that, and let render your page. There you will see how asp.net does it. They have some own disable logic. Maybe you can adapt that somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uk3b/3/) which has two inputs (one is required) and two buttons (one is submit).

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form1" method="get" action="http://example.com">
<input id="q" required />
<input id="w"  />

<input id="btn" type="button" value="Cancel" />
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

**Javascript**

```
    $('#form1').on("submit", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

If that doesn't answer your question, please elaborate

Comment: please read comments om Luke's answer, and have a look a this http://jsfiddle.net/8uk3b/2/